# Esri WFS in OWSLib?

Tags: qgis, python, wfs, owslib

I'm trying to use [this WFS service](http://gis-services.metria.se/arcgis/rest/services/nv/InspireNV_WFS_NVR/MapServer/) with OWSLib in Python, but can't figure out how to make it work. I would like to know if it is even possible, and if so, what I'm doing wrong.

It's a bit hard to figure out how the URL should be formatted. This is the code I have so far, just to test if I can get a response.

```
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService
wfs = WebFeatureService(url="http://gis-services.metria.se/arcgis/rest/services/nv/InspireNV_WFS_NVR/MapServer")
print(wfs.identification.title)
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bla\test_2.py", line 50, in <module>
    wfs11 = WebFeatureService(url="http://gis-services.metria.se/arcgis/rest/services/nv/InspireNV_WFS_NVR/MapServer")
  File "C:\Users\bla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\owslib\wfs.py", line 40, in WebFeatureService
    password=password)
  File "C:\Users\bla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\owslib\feature\wfs100.py", line 77, in __new__
    username=username, password=password)
  File "C:\Users\bla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\owslib\feature\wfs100.py", line 101, in __init__
    self._capabilities = reader.read(self.url)
  File "C:\Users\bla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\owslib\feature\common.py", line 56, in read
    return etree.fromstring(u.read())
  File "C:\Users\bla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1314, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: undefined entity: line 113, column 0
```

The little I manage to gather from that is that it gets the response, but doesn't know what to do with it.

I also tried adding the WFS in Qgis, where I get the layer list, layers can be added without error, but just loads forever.

Comment: The URL ending with "MapServer" is not the WFS endpoint.  Maybe try http://gis-services.metria.se/arcgis/rest/services/nv/InspireNV_WFS_NVR/MapServer/WFSServer? instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [ArcGIS for INSPIRE documentation](https://server.arcgis.com/en/inspire/10.3/inspire-services/use-the-inspire-feature-download-service.htm), I worked out that the service endpoint for your INSPIRE WFS service is not the URL you give but instead:

```
http://gis-services.metria.se/arcgis/rest/services/nv/InspireNV_WFS_NVR/MapServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?
```

For example to get the default GetCapabilities response you would use the following request:

[Default WFS GetCapabilities request](http://gis-services.metria.se/arcgis/rest/services/nv/InspireNV_WFS_NVR/MapServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&)

The following owslib code works for me to access the service:

```
from owslib import wfs as wfs

wfs_end_point = "http://gis-services.metria.se/arcgis/rest/services/nv/InspireNV_WFS_NVR/MapServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?"
w_200 = wfs.WebFeatureService(wfs_end_point, version='2.0.0')

print("Service is: " + w_200.identification.title)
print("\nHas the following FeatureTypes:\n")
for l in w_200.contents:
    print(l)
```